# Deploying Ruby-Tk app on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, deployment, tk-toolkit

I'm looking for a straightforward way to deploy a standalone Ruby-Tk desktop app on OS X. All existing options for deploying desktop Ruby GUI apps on the Mac (e.g. standaloneify.rb) assume that you are using RubyCocoa or MacRuby, and are tightly bound to Xcode/Interface Builder project structure; or, alternatively, that you are wrapping a simple script via Platypus that does not involve deploying the entire Ruby runtime. None of the other existing options that I've found--rubyscript2exe, ocra, crate--support the Mac and/or support Ruby 1.9.

I'm hoping that someone can point me to a shell script or Ruby script that does the following:

1. Tracks all dependencies/gems in an app.
2. Copies the Ruby interpreter and dependencies into an application bundle.
3. Runs install_name_tool on the Ruby interpreter and all dylibs to make them portable.

The application bundle can either be something created by Platypus, use a Cocoa stub launcher, or even a shell script--I know how to handle those. The problem I'm having is getting the Ruby runtime wrapped in a portable way.

There's a rakefile at http://weft-qda.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/weft-qda/rake/rake_osx.rb that encompasses the tasks that I'm looking to achieve, but this rakefile is part of a larger build structure that I can't get running on my Mac. I'm not familiar enough with rakefile structure to refactor this into a simple script that I can run, either via "ruby rake_osx.rb" or even "rake".

If someone can suggest to me how to modify this rakefile to run independently, or point me to another example project, or even share some code, I would be grateful. The project I am working on is better suited for Ruby than Python (better library support in Ruby), but I am not going to invest time in it if deployment won't work. (Python has a much richer tradition of deployment tools than Ruby, something I'v never quite understood.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit late after the fact, but in classic fashion, since I could not find a desktop app deployment tool for Ruby-Tk on the Mac, I wrote my own:

[ruby2app](https://github.com/codebykevin/ruby2app)

ruby2app is a simple command-line tool, inspired by similar Mac tools like py2app for Python, that bundles a Ruby script with the Ruby runtime into a standalone Mac application. It reads a basic configuration file to find the appropriate Ruby installation, compiles a small C program that embeds the Ruby interpreter, copies the entire Ruby installation into the application bundle, and re-links the relevant libraries with the main executable.

It attempts to provide for the Mac what ocra and exerb provide for Windows. Hopefully this will be of use to others.